# Special characters showing up in database

Tags: php, mysql, special-characters

I'm saving a string to the db that contains a ® symbol. I need it in this format so it can be displayed in a pdf I'm creating.

Everytime I submit the form and push it into the db it comes back as Â®

I'm programming in PHP

I'm using:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

And my column in the db is set to utf8_general_ci

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You should really be encoding those characters.

Comment: I don't have that option

Comment: How are you loading data into your database? Are you using a server side scripting language?

Comment: That character you gave usually translated to newline, if I remember my debugging days correctly. Can you do a HEX(field) on it? HEX will allow us to see the "raw" chacaters that are stored

Comment: Sorry, I'm coding in PHP

Comment: Give us a code sample of how you're saving the data to the database so we can see what might be wrong.